# Import zxing into Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing

Once I've downloaded the zip from github and extracted it, how do I integrate it into Android Studio? I need zxing to scan QR codes and I'm developing on Android Lollipop. I think I only need the android and core folders but I don't exactly know what to do with them. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call a qrscanner activity, scan a qr and get results back. You don't need to import whole project. You can do(This needs qr scanner application by zxing downloaded in phone):

1. Call qrscanner activity by using intent like below in your oncreate method:

   `try {
           Intent scanActivityIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
           scanActivityIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
           startActivityForResult(scanActivityIntent, 0);
       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
           showDialog(context, "No Scanner Found!", "Download a scanner app from market?", "Download",
                   "Don't Download");
       }`
2. Create a function so that if activity is not found(QR scanner App is not installed), it will prompt to download application by zxing from play store.

   ```
   private AlertDialog showDialog(Activity activity, String title, String message, String posButton,
   String negButton) {
   final Activity dialogActivity = activity;
   AlertDialog.Builder dlPromptDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
   dlPromptDialog.setTitle(title);
   dlPromptDialog.setMessage(message);
   dlPromptDialog.setPositiveButton(posButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
       try {
           Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");

           Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
           dialogActivity.startActivity(downloadIntent);
       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   });

   dlPromptDialog.setNegativeButton(negButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
       context.finish();
   }
   });

   return dlPromptDialog.show();
   }
   ```
3. Get result from QRScanner in onActivityResult method.

Comment: I need to customize the barcode scanner view so I don't think this solution is suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Goto File->Project Structure->In the dialog press the Green "+" button on the top left side. From there select "Import Gradle Project"(if its a gradle project) or "Import Eclipse ADT project"(if the lib is an eclipse project).->Next->Select the Downloaded(Extracted) lib.

Now the lib is added as a module in your Project. Once the Build process is complete, Once again Goto File->Project Structure-> Click on your "app" module->Click on "Dependencies" tab->Click on the green "+" button on the top right corner.->Module dependency->Select the Module from the dialog->OK

DONE

By Adding the whole lib into your project, the user won't be prompted to download an external QR code scanner from your application.

Comment: I have the zxing-master folder. I was not able to integrate it either as lib or gradle or eclipse project. What's the case here?